# Attribute Table Option not showing up QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I uploaded a file to qgis and can see the map and layers. When I right-click the layer trying to see an attribute table, there is no option to click the attribute table at all. Why may this be?

Comment: Please describe the type of file that you opened in the QGIS. Is it a raster or a vector file? If it is a vector, is it a shapefile, geopackage, tab file, or any different file type? Please add more information.

Comment: Please give more information about the Software (including the Version) as well as the data you are using. Maybe add a link to the data or share a screenshot.

Comment: Where do you "right-click the layer"? Without adding more information and a screenshot, it's difficult to help